# How do I use stress-ng to simulate memory usage?

Tags: unix, memory, memory-usage, stress-testing

I found the command `stress-ng -c 0 -l 60` which takes up 60% of the CPU. Is there a similar command for taking a certain percentage of the total memory available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running a Linux flavour your distribution may include a [numactl](https://github.com/numactl/numactl) package and otherwise grab the source for the [`memhog`](https://github.com/numactl/numactl/blob/master/memhog.c) utility included in there from github.